# Does anyone attribute the copper snake to a mythbuster scheme?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, chukas

We are familiar with the copper snake in chapter 21 of Parshas Chukkas used to remedy the Bnei Yisrael when bitten by the snakes sent to punish them.

Recently I was made aware of a Greek mythological figure named Asclepious who was a healer with a snake on a stick from where this symbol has become popular in the American medical field, see https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19125/why-is-the-snake-or-asp-the-primary-logo-of-medicinal-organisations/19126?noredirect=1#comment49549_19126

In one of the comments to my assumed wrong answer, someone suggests a common source myth for both the Torah and the Greeks.

There have been many ideas raised where certain stories in the Torah were specifically chosen so as to eradicate the belief in these ideas from the minds of the people, and prove that Hashem is running the world. The a Malbim has quite a few of these ideas in the geneology listed in Bereishis. Chaim Navon says the Taninim mentioned in Bereishis were also to combat the ancient belief that the world was created by a giant serpent.

Does anyone say that Hashem chose this snake on a stick symbol, what was perhaps a common healing occult artifact to prove that He is the only healer, not any other being with a snake on a stick?

Comment: I don't see any reason not to believe that the Greeks took it from the Jews. After all, they did force us to translate the entire Torah into Greek.

Comment: @Moshe this myth of theirs is dated to around the time of Mattan Torah. The translating didn't happen for many centuries afterwards.

Comment: I wasn't saying that the Greeks definitely got it from the translation, just pointing out that there have been historical interactions. But, more importantly, does the Greek myth exist in writings from the period, or is it later scholars' writing something they claim about that period?  If that is the case, them it could indeed have come from the later translation.

Comment: @Moshe True. It could be. I have no problem saying they got it from us either. Im not posting it as a bible critique question. Just an interesting fact that might belong on a list of other anti-myths. Maybe. That's why i asked.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say

Comment: @Shmuel about what?

Comment: @Shmuel imagine an image of a common god, who has an occult object, to whom is ascribed certain wondrous powers. Now imagine Hashem saying to take that object and use it for that said wondrous power. That would show that there is no god behind that power, rather Hashem is the one controlling that power. See for instance Malbim in Bereishis 6 2 where he explains the psukim about the bnei elohim as a combative idea against ancient beliefs of gods mating with mortals.

Comment: @Shmuel i thought about that too. But that's why I'm focusing on the occult item without it's deity. Along the lines of the ramma in hilchos avoda zara quoting rishonim that only pictures of celestial bodies with their associated deities are problematic, not the celestial bodies by themselves. Obviously this is not a real analogy, just a line of thinking.

Comment: Dead link and read with caution (respectively), but connections between the asklepian, the caduceus, and l'havdil the nechustan are discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_of_Asclepius#cite_note-18 and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehushtan#cite_note-11

Comment: @SAH what do you mean by dead link? And thanks.

Comment: @User6591 I mean apparently there is nothing at the link [anymore]. No problem!